# Regex in javascript in a very specific format

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a input that has to format what's the user typing(actually it is info from his bank account). But the numbers have to be formatted in a certain way:

- the first 5 digits must be numbers.
- if the user type more than 5 numbers, the last number must have a '-' before it
- after the 5 digit, the user can type 'x' or 'X'
- the number can have minimun of 5 digits, and maximum of 15

examples:

- 12345
- 12345-1
- 123456-1
- 1234567-1
- 12345-x
- 123456789-x
- 123456789-X
- 12345678901234-5

Actually I'm using a normalizer that replaces the string.

This is what I'm using but I cant format it correctly.

```
export const normalizeBankAccount = value => {
    if (!value) {
      return value
    }

    if(value.length <= 16 && (!value.match(/[^\d|X]/g) || !value.match(/[^\d|-]/g) || !value.match(/[^\d|x]/g))) {
      if(value.length <= 5){
        return value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
      } else if(value.length >= 6) {
        const len = value.length;
        const aux=value;
        const initial = value.substring(0,value.length-1).replace('-', '');
        console.log("len: " +len, "\naux: " +aux,"\ninitial: "+ initial)
        return value.replace(new RegExp("\\d{"+ len +"}") , initial+ '-').replace(/[X]/g, '-X').replace(/[x]/g, '-x')
      }
    }
}
```

When I use this method, the string is formatted like this:

- 12345-6789123

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look for a given length, followed by a single character and add a minus sign.

```js
const
    normalize = string => string.replace(/^\d{5,14}(?=[0-9x]$)/i, '$&-');

console.log(['12345', '123451', '1234561', '12345671', '12345x', '123456789x', '123456789X', '123456789012345'].map(normalize));
```

Example with input.

```js
function update(element) {
    element.value = element.value
        .replace(/[^0-9x]/gi, '')
        .replace(/x(?=.)/gi, '')
        .replace(/^\d{5,14}(?=[0-9x]$)/i, '$&-');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="update(this)" id="x">
```

Comment: It actually don't work because the numbers must be formatted as the user keeps typing

Comment: you need to clean the string from all minus signs and apply the normalization.

Comment: Almost working, I removed the minus sign as you said like this:
`
string.replace('-', '').replace(/^\d{5,14}(?=[0-9x]$)/i, '$&-')
`
But I cant type x or X

Comment: do you have some other filtering?

Comment: No, its just this

Comment: replace(/-/g, '') => I didnt know this is the correct way to do it, now it's working =), thank you so much

Comment: the replace with a string, instead of a regular expression replace only the first occurence of the find. the version with a regex and a global flag searches for all occurences.

Comment: Can you help with one more thing? I would like to not allow the user to type anything that is not 0-9, x or X, because this way, the user can type any character

Comment: you could remove unwanted characters. maybe you need another check for shorter items with `'x'`.

Comment: This way is working, and shorter items is already not accepting 'x', because I added a condition